# How to provide schema for command args in a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Some built-in commands such as `workbench.action.tasks.runTask` provide a schema for their args, which enables auto-completion when creating a keybinding to invoke that command.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/0d5e948d863153807cfe07ecd20dc10374eea6d2/src/vs/workbench/contrib/tasks/browser/abstractTaskService.ts#L421-L446

[image]

Can extensions also provide an args schema for their contributed commands? If so, how?

Comment: You should add a link to your github issue so it gets more visibility (and upvotes) .  I upvoted it, I think this is a much needed feature (and with the team member who has taken ownership of the issue I think it will get done sooner than later).

Comment: The link to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a discussion in a vscode repository there is not an officially supported way of providing a schema for command arguments. 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/541

And this has led to a feature request 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178505

As a workaround, it's technically possible to contribute additional validation to keybindings.json files and provide a schema and autocompletion through that.

Here is an example from my own extension:

```json
// package.json
"contributes": {
  "jsonValidation": [
    {
      "fileMatch": "%APP_SETTINGS_HOME%/keybindings.json",
      "url": "./src/commands.schema.jsonc"
    },
    {
      "fileMatch": "%APP_SETTINGS_HOME%/profiles/*/keybindings.json",
      "url": "./src/commands.schema.jsonc"
    }
  ],
}
```

```json
// custom.schema.json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "if": {
      "required": [ "command" ],
      "properties": { "command": { "const": "akbyrd.task.runWithArgs" } }
    },
    "then": {
      "required": [ "args" ],
      "properties": {
        "args": {
          "type": [ "string", "object" ]
        }
      },
      "if": {
        "properties": { "args": { "type": "object" } }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "args": {
            "required": [ "task" ],
            "properties": {
              "task": {
                "description": "The standard arguments to workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
                "type": [ "string", "object" ]
              },
              "taskArgs": {
                "description": "An object filled task arguments. Keys are argument names and values are argument values.",
                "type": "object",
                "patternProperties": {
                  ".*": { "not": { "type": [ "object", "array" ] } }
                }
              }
            },
            "defaultSnippets": [
              { "bodyText": "{ \"task\": \"${1:taskName}\", \"taskArgs\": { \"${4:argName}\": \"${5:argValue}\" } }" }
            ],
            "if": {
              "properties": { "task": { "type": "object"} }
            },
            "then": {
              "properties": {
                "task": {
                  "properties": {
                    "task": { "type": "string" },
                    "type": { "type": "string" }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops, that was a double paste. Fixed now

Comment: is `%APP_SETTINGS_HOME%` a VSC variable on Windows or does it also apply to Linux and MacOS

Comment: I don't know, I just searched the codebase to find how other things affected keybindings.json. Most likely it applies to all platforms, if I had to guess. I can see at least one place where it's being built with `os.homedir()`